# "Cannot find symbol: Method" but method is defined and declared in Storm.java

Tags: java, constructor

In my driver program methods: setDuration, setWind, setPressure, NewStorm, getCategory cannot not be found although they are clearly declared in my Storm.java file. I can't refer to any of them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StormChaser {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // Constants
final int MAX_STORMS = 200;

Storm[] List = new Storm[MAX_STORMS]; // array of Storms
Storm CurrentStorm;      // storm returned by GetStorm
int NStorms = 0;         // number in array List
int Total = 0;           // total number of storms in the input file
Scanner fileInput;

   // Openning hurricane data file
   try{
    System.out.println("Openning hurricane data file...");
    fileInput = new Scanner(new File("hurricane.data"));
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    return;
   }
   System.out.println( "File opened successfully...");
   System.out.println( "Reading file..." );


   // Read Storm data from file until EOF

   while( fileInput.hasNextLine()) 
   {
    CurrentStorm = GetStorm(fileInput);
       ++Total; 
    if( CurrentStorm.getCategory() >= 3 )
    {
            List[NStorms++] = CurrentStorm; 
    }
}
System.out.println( "Number of storms: " + Total);
System.out.println( "Hurricanes with category 3 and above: " + NStorms );
DisplayStorms( "First Ten Storms", List, 10 );
Sort( List, NStorms );
DisplayStorms( "Top Ten Storms", List, 10 );
fileInput.close();
}

public static Storm GetStorm( Scanner in ) 
{
   // Build a Storm object and return it

int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, sequence = 0, wind = 0, pressure 
= 0;
String name = new String(); 
double junk = 0.0;
    int current = 0, beginDate = 0, duration = 0;
Storm NewStorm; 

    // Check for end of file
    if( !in.hasNextLine() )
    {
        NewStorm = new Storm(beginDate, duration, name, wind, pressure);
        return NewStorm;
    }       

// Read next record.
year = in.nextInt();
    month = in.nextInt();
    day = in.nextInt();
    hour = in.nextInt();
    sequence = in.nextInt();
    name =  in.next();
    junk = in.nextDouble();
    junk = in.nextDouble();
    wind = in.nextInt();
    pressure = in.nextInt();


    // Make a storm object and initialize it with info from the current 
record
    beginDate = year * 10000 + month * 100 + day;
    NewStorm = new Storm(beginDate, duration, name, wind, pressure);
    current = sequence;


    while( in.hasNextLine() && current == sequence) 
    {
        //update storm info
            duration += 6;
            NewStorm.setDuration(duration);
            NewStorm.SetWind(wind);
            NewStorm.setPressure(pressure);


        //get next record 

    }

   // and return the new storm object
   return NewStorm;
}

public static void DisplayStorms( String title, Storm[] List, int NStorms ) 
{
   // display NStorms storms
   // print some title and column headings
    System.out.println(title + "\n");
    System.out.println("Begin Date   Duration   Name   Category   Maximum    
Minimum");
    System.out.println("             (hours)                     Winds (mph) 
Press. (mb)");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------
----
--------");
    for( int k = 0; k < NStorms; k++ )
        System.out.println(List[k].toString());
    System.out.println ("\n");
}

public static void Sort( Storm[] StormList, int N ) 
{
    // bubble sort the list of Storms
    int pass = 0, k, switches;
    Storm temp;
    switches = 1;
    while( switches != 0 ) 
    {
        switches = 0;
        pass++;
        for( k = 0; k < N - pass; k++ ) 
        {
            if( StormList[k].getCategory() < StormList[k+1].getCategory() )
            {
                temp = StormList[k];
                StormList[k] = StormList[k+1];
                StormList[k+1] = temp;
                switches = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the Storm.java.

```
public class Storm {
    private final double KnotsToMPH = 1.15;

// global user-defined types:
private int beginDate = 0;
private int duration = 0;
private String name;
private int category = 0;
private int wind = 0;
private int pressure = 0;

public Storm( int bdate, int dur, String sname, int w, int p )
{
beginDate = bdate;
setDuration(dur);
name = sname;
wind = 0;
pressure = 0;
setWind(w);
setPressure(p);
}

public void setDuration( int d )
{
duration = d;        
}

public void setWind( int w )
{
double temp = 0.0;       
temp = KnotsToMPH * w;
if(temp > wind)
    wind = (int)temp;
SaffirSimpson();

}

public void setPressure( int p )
{
if(pressure == 0)
    pressure = p;
if(pressure > p && p != 0)
    pressure = p;
SaffirSimpson();
}

public void SaffirSimpson()
{
// Compute storm category, using the Saffir-Simpson scale
if(pressure <= 920 && wind >= 156)
{
    category = 5;   // Category 5
}
if(pressure > 920 && wind < 156)
{
category = 4;   // Category 4
}
if(pressure > 945 && wind < 113)
{
    category = 3;   // Category 3
}
if(pressure > 965 && wind < 96)
{
    category = 2;   // Category 2
}    
if(pressure > 980 && wind < 83)
{
    category = 1;   // Category 1
}
if(wind < 64)
{
    category = -1;  // Tropical Storm
}    
if(wind < 34)
{
    category = -2;  // Tropical Depression
}
if(pressure == 0)
{
    category = 0;   // Missing pressure
}
}

public int getCategory()
{
return category;    
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%9d %8d   %10s %4d %9d %10d\n", beginDate, 
duration, 
name, category, wind, pressure); 

}

}
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the default constructor that NetBeans creates, I'm just not sure where that exact problem is located..

Comment: Please get in the habit of following Java naming conventions.  Class names are in camel case with the first letter uppercase.  Variables and methods are camel case with the first letter lowercase.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will, thank you.

Comment: Java is case sensitive, `SetWind` is not the same as `setWind`

Comment: I would also strongly recommend that you do some research into "string formatting in Java", it will help you to no end

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm an idiot.... Is that the problem? Also is there a preference in changing the names from either file?

Comment: [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) would recommend that all method and variable names begin with a lower case character

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive, `SetWind` is not the same as `setWind`

The method in `Storm` is defined as `setWind`

```
public static class Storm {
    //...
    public void setWind(int w) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

But you are using `SetWind` in you code `NewStorm.SetWind(wind);`

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that but there is still a "cannot find symbol" error in NewStorm.setWind(wind) and for duration and pressure